# I installed the composer-cli globally but it shows me error

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I installed the composer-cli globally but it shows me error

"-bash: composer: command not found" at mac os sierra

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you did not install using `sudo` and that you check that the install **actually** worked. e.g. it will fail if you don't have XCode installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes to add to the point mentioned above.After installing Xcode it didnt work out for me . So i changed my node version from

> 11

to

> 8.8.15

and did `npm install -g composer-cli`. It worked for me .